# how do you stress test a wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf

What tools and techniques have you used for testing your wcf services?  Where there any special considerations made for the type of hosting you used(ie windows service vs IIS vs WAS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[WCF Load Test](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/)** should be the right tool, however it seem to require *Visual Studio Team System*. I cannot confirm as the installer didn't work properly on my office machine.

**[wcfstorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx)** seem also to do the job but it's not free (the [lite version](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/wcfstorm-lite.aspx) doesn't seem to have the load testing feature).

So far the best was to create it myself. Using some Stopwatch(), using an one threads per client. By varying the number of threads and the frequency of the calls I could get the average response time for example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [patterns & practices Performance Testing Guidance Project](http://perftesting.codeplex.com/). Also check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2008/05/05/asp-net-performance-engineering-stress-test-your-architecture-design-and-code.aspx) great blog posts; not specific to WCF, but you can carry over a lot of lessons. :)

I've heard [some people](http://tellagostudios.com/wcf-load-testing-so-aware-test-workbench) use [SO-Aware](http://www.tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware-test-workbench%E2%84%A2) to load-test WCF.

Also, to comment on something Wernight said, to use WCFLoadTest, you do need [at least the Test Edition of VSTS](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/products/cc149003.aspx).

Finally, check out [this KB page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282) from Microsoft.